# Hover color cross-site for each color

Tags: css, less

If I have the following variable:

```
@text-c: #cccccc;
```

Is there a way to specify the hover variant of the color (in this case the colour `#aaaaaa`) so it applies cross-site, without having to add it in each separate `:hover` rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mixin](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature) and [extend](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) are probably what you're looking for. The variable itself does not say yet how or where you use it (be it either for some `color` property or not) or if you use it at all. 
So instead of relying on some indirect logic, as there's no way for compiler to guess to insert `:hover {color: #aaaaaa}` for every element that has `color: #cccccc`, first of all because `:hover` "sub-style" is not inherited across elements like properties do (e.g. what if you just set `body {color: @text-c}`?), make it explicit, e.g. (not optimized variant just to illustrate the method):

```
// "color team"
.text-c() {
    color: #cccccc;
    &:hover {color: #aaaaaa}
}

// usage 

div.zoo {
    .text-c();
}

span.park {
    .text-c();
}

td#life {
    .text-c();
}

// etc.
```

An actual optimized (most likely `extend`ing some template instead of copying the same properties every time) would depend on how/where/how-often/etc. you're going to use it and (not-less-important) how (and if) you plan it to be customized (for example see @Harry's answer on how to make a generic mixin instead of color-value-hardcoded like I did above).

Comment: Looks like OP was only looking for the hard coded color value option.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the variable value to be set in one common place instead of at multiple locations, you could create another variable and use the `darken` function to obtain the `hover` variant of it.

Below is a sample snippet for this.

```
@text-c: #cccccc;
@text-c-hover: darken(@text-c, 13.5%);

a{
    color: @text-c;
    &:hover{
        color: @text-c-hover;
    }
}
```

On the other hand if you want to write the `hover` selector itself at only one place then you can use a mixin with the parent selector (`&`) and invoke it all  relevant places like in the below snippet. This will set the hover text color for the element as 13.5% darker the default text color.

```
.hover(@input){
    &:hover{
        color: darken(@input, 13.5%);
    }
}

#demo{
    @color: #aaaaaa;
    color: @color;
    .hover(@color);
}
```